# Case Customer does not want to be contact by email - Email publisher warning

Tags: service-cloud-console, casefeed

I just came across this stange warning in the Service Cloud Console. 
When I try to send an email to a customer from the case feed email publisher I get following warning:

[image]

It's not affected by the contacts you select so it has to do with the accountn that is set on the case. I have been trying to find out what triggers this but I can't seem to find any documentation about it.

Anyone who can explain this warning and how it's triggered?

Thanks!
Lieven

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing it's because the EmailOptOut field on the contact is checked?

Comment: Actually, that is a correct answer.

Comment: It's indeed the correct answer. We had a workflow that was flagging that checkbox when our contact was end dated. Removing the flag did indeed remove the warning. Thanks for your help!